# Any Resources for Pure Actionscript 3 Games?

Tags: actionscript

What resources (books or website/tutorials) are available, that cover game development using *pure* Actionscript 3 code? By pure, I mean *not* using Flash CS4 and its timeline, and *not* using Flex MXML components. Everything done using only Actionscript code.

In another question, I asked about using certain objects of the Flex SDK for simple games, and the consensus was that I shouldn't use it *at all*, but only Actionscript for a game. Sounds reasonable, but the books/website tutorials that I have found on the subject of games, all use AS3 in the context of Flash CS4. They assume your objects will be movieclips, with timelines, etc.

I realize that you can learn game programming from books in other languages, and/or ignore the Flash aspect of AS3 books. I guess what I'm looking for, is whatever information is specific to AS3, such as best practices for AS3-only games, how to make architectural/design decisions, etc. If it exists, anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Flash Adventure Game Tutorial
  series](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/11/22/create-your-own-flash-adventure-game.aspx) shows you how to create a
  Flash adventure game with Flex and
  ActionScript.
- [FlexFighters](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/09/03/flash-game-development-with-flex-and-actionscript.aspx)
  shows you how to make a shoot'em'up
  with Flex and ActionScript.
- [This is a tutorial series](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/07/11/away3d-tutorial.aspx) that shows you how to make a 3D Flash game with Flex and Away3D

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [Flixel](http://flixel.org/).

> What is flixel?
>
> flixel is a completely free collection of Actionscript 3 files that helps organize, automate, and optimize Flash games; an object-oriented framework that lets anyone create original and complex games with thousands of objects on screen in just a few hours.

Flixel is licensed under the MIT license and the site has quite a few tutorials to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

A site that is basically all about using just pure AS3 and that now has game tutorials centered around his pure AS3 game making library is [www.actiontad.com](http://www.actiontad.com).

Your games may be smaller using only AS3 and the SDK, but you loose the ability to animate with a timeline, animations made with the timeline in Flash will perform better, than say sticking a whole bunch of .pngs together, which is a technique actiontad uses, but that site is coming into it's own now with the library he recently released, if pure AS3 game making is your thing it's worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy your games on mobile (iOS/Android) you should take advantage of Starling (http://gamua.com/starling/), 2D rendering engine built on top of Stage3D, which gives you GPU raw power.